# Angular Formly - Remove attribute when field is hidden

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Currently, I have a formly field that becomes hidden based on the value of another field (using hideExpression). However, say I want to make this hidden field required, only if it is not hidden. How could this be accomplished? I was thinking along the lines of removing the "required" attribute, but I was not sure how to do this. Examples of my fields are below:

```
{
    key: 'check',
    type: 'checkbox',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'check',
        options: [],
        required: false
    }
},

{
    key: 'test',
    type: 'select',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'test',
        options: [],
        required: true,
    },
        hideExpression: '!model.check'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [`expressionProperties`](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-formly-expressionproperties?pl=7) to set the `required` attribute. Like [so](https://jsbin.com/gaqemi/edit?html,js,output):

```
vm.fields = [
  {
    key: 'one',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {label: 'One'},
  },
  {
    key: 'two',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {label: 'Two'},
    expressionProperties: {
      'templateOptions.required': '!!model.one',
    },
  },
]
```